# Change list elements with updated numerical order

Tags: list, python-3.8

I have a list as follows:

```
L1 = ['asd', 'pqr', 'Mn2', 'Mn3', 'xyz']
L2 = ['asd', 'pqr', 'Mn7', 'Mn8', 'Mn9', 'xyz']
```

I am trying to get the following:

```
L1 = ['asd', 'pqr', 'Mn1', 'Mn2', 'xyz']
L2 = ['asd', 'pqr', 'Mn1', 'Mn2', 'Mn3', 'xyz']
```

i.e. everytime the `Mn1, Mn2, ...` series occurs in the list, I need to change them to update their chronology. In the `L2`, `Mn7, Mn8, Mn9` were updated to `Mn1, Mn2, Mn3`.

The `Mn` series cam be of an arbitrary number i.e. `Mn11, Mn12, Mn13, Mn14` etc also but whenever they happen they are in numerical order

I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to substitute the numbers. For example:

```py
import re
from itertools import count


L1 = ["asd", "pqr", "Mn2", "Mn3", "xyz"]
L2 = ["asd", "pqr", "Mn7", "Mn8", "Mn9", "xyz"]


def change(lst):
    c, pat = count(1), re.compile(r"Mn(\d+)")
    return [pat.sub(lambda x: f"Mn{next(c)}", v) for v in lst]


L1 = change(L1)
L2 = change(L2)

print(L1)
print(L2)
```

Prints:

```py
['asd', 'pqr', 'Mn1', 'Mn2', 'xyz']
['asd', 'pqr', 'Mn1', 'Mn2', 'Mn3', 'xyz']
```